# Sort Multidimensional array by Number

Tags: vb.net, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort a 2 dimensional array. The first column is a number and the second one is a word.

So far I am using:

```
myarray.Sort(Function(x, y) x(1).CompareTo(y(1)))
```

but it only sorts in alphabetical order, and I need it to sort in numerical order

Comment: your array *cannot* contain mixed types they are most likely actually both string.  Please show the declaration.

Comment: Dim mylist As New List(Of String()) . It then adds into the list from a datatable

Comment: `Of String()` means both items are strings - no numbers.  If the values (numbers) are unique you could use a SortedDictionary(Of int, string) otherwise to retain the value you will need a class for your list

Answer (score 2):

Once you store a numbers as a string it cannot act as a number any longer because it is a numeral (a *character* representing a number).  This is especially true of sorting where "9" will evaluate greater than "10000" everytime.  Rather than a string array, use a utility class to store the Name and Value as a `NamedValuePair`:

```
Public Class NVP
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As Integer

    Public Sub New(n As String, v As Integer)
        Name = n
        Value = v
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} ({1})", Name, Value.ToString)
    End Function
End Class
```

Then store those in your list:

```
Private myList As New List(Of NVP)
```

For a simple sort on the value member:

```
' populate some fake data
myList.Add(New NVP("Ziggy", 6))
myList.Add(New NVP("Apple", 1))
myList.Add(New NVP("Zebra", 152))
myList.Add(New NVP("Zoey", 7))

' Sort or OrderBy are not methods, so create a new list in the desired order:
myList = myList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Value).ToList()
```

---

The NVP class can be very handy for a lots of situations.  To make it even *more* useful, define it as Generic so it can be declared as string/decimal or string/Date, string Point etc etc etc:

```
Public Class NVP(Of T)
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As T

    Public Sub New(n As String, v As T)
        Name = n
        Value = v
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} ({1})", Name, Value.ToString)
    End Function
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim foo As New NVP(Of Integer)(strName, intVal)   ' int type

Dim myList As New List(Of NVP(Of Double))         ' double type
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use a `SortedDictionary(Of Int32, String)` or maybe a regular `Dictionary(Of Int32, String)` and then do the sorting using LINQ or such?

Comment: that is what I suggested in a comment, but we dont know if any of the data is guaranteed to be unique (dont really know *anything* about the data)

Comment: Doh. Didn't see that comment, and I did assume that the number value would be unique since it was said it would be sorted on.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around, I found an answer to my problem.

Convert the second column to an integer and then sort.

Then you can put in back into a `.tolist`

```
myarray = myarray.OrderByDescending(Function(r) Convert.ToInt32(r(1))).ToList()
```